# Custom file location for Log4j : logs not getting created

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

I am trying to implement custom app logs by creating `log4j.properties` file with a custom file location as below. File is kept at 
scr/main/recources

`log4j.appender.FILE.File=/home/ec2-user/Log/Scanlog.out`

I can't find logs created on this location on linux server from where I am running code. I have given full permission to path and spark-summit is through ec2-user only.

I have tried with `log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/user/PI/Log/Scanlog.out`
and it works fine in local, but on linux server.

Comment: while running the application did you provide log4j.conf . file using java options for driver and worker? When you deploy the application you need to provice log4j conf files as a java options `spark-submit --class MAIN_CLASS --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:PATH_OF_LOG4J" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:PATH_OF_LOG4J" --master MASTER_IP:PORT JAR_PATH`